# Convert List[ValidationNEL[String, Unit]] to ValidationNEL[String, Unit]

Tags: scala, scalaz

Is there a standard way to flatten the left sides into a single list?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but the `Monoid` instance should do the trick:

```
scala> List(
     |   println("test").successNel[String],
     |   "a".failNel[Unit],
     |   "b".failNel[Unit]
     | ).suml == Failure(NonEmptyList("a", "b"))
test
res0: Boolean = true
```

Where `suml` is a method that's pimped onto any collection full of something with a `Monoid` instance.

Comment: that's what i need, but is this a scalaz7 feature only?

Comment: You should be able to use `.asMA.sum` instead of `.suml` in Scalaz 6.

Comment: ok, i am closer, but not there yet, it's complaining that there is no implicit value defined for m, which is the Monoid

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is some code that does the trick:

```
scala> type MyValidationNEL[A] = ValidationNEL[String, A]
defined type alias MyValidationNEL

scala> val x: List[MyValidationNEL[Unit]] = 
     | List("a".failNel, "b".failNel)
x: List[MyValidationNEL[Unit]] = List(Failure(NonEmptyList(a)), Failure(NonEmptyList(b)))

scala> x.sequence
res57: MyValidationNEL[List[Unit]] = Failure(NonEmptyList(a, b))

scala>
```

I've taken part of the example from this presentation:
http://www.scribd.com/doc/93526802/Bjarnason-Scalaz
by 
Rúnar Bjarnason
http://scalaz.org

Comment: Please don't do it like that. Use sequenceU instead. Than you will be able to ommit this whole magic.

Comment: @goroncy, yes, actually, I ended up collecting Failures and then doing a foldLeft on them with |+| operatior.